# Problem while using streambuilder on 2D list as I had to use StreamBuilder for my Flutter project but the code is just printing 2 rows on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**I am trying to build a grid using 2D list of Gesture Detector whose child will be a Container.
I don't know why, but the code is just printing 2 rows of the list. First I tried to build the grid using 1D list and it worked. But I want to use a 2D list because I want to use the column number and the row number as coordinates in my flutter project.**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _sampleSize = 612;
  int _sampleSizei = 34;
  int _sampleSizej = 18;

  List<List<GestureDetector>> _gridBox = List.generate(
      34, (index) => List<GestureDetector>.generate(18, (index) => null));

  int duration = 500;
  StreamController<List<List<GestureDetector>>> _streamController =
      StreamController();
  Stream _stream;
  int speed = 0;
  Duration _getDuration() {
    return Duration(microseconds: duration);
  }

  _checkAndResetIfSorted() async {
    if (isSorted) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    }
  }

  _find_path(int i) {}

  _changeColor(int i, int j) {
    _gridBox[i][j] = GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        height: 27,
        width: 25,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
   
    _streamController.add(_gridBox);
  }

  _setSortAlgo(String type) {
    setState(() {
      _currentSortAlgo = type;
    });
  }
  _generateBoxes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _sampleSizei; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < _sampleSizej; j++) {
        _gridBox[i][j] = (GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => _changeColor(i, j),
          child: Container(
            height: 27,
            width: 25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_randomise();
    _generateBoxes();
    _streamController = StreamController<List<List<GestureDetector>>>();
    _stream = _streamController.stream;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(' Dijkstra'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            initialValue: _currentSortAlgo,
            itemBuilder: (ctx) {
              return [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'Dijkstra',
                  child: Text("Dijkstra"),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'A star',
                  child: Text("A star"),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'Bi directional Dijkstra',
                  child: Text("Bi directional Dijkstra"),
                ),
              ];
            },
            onSelected: (String value) {
              // _randomise();
              _setSortAlgo(value);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
                initialData: _gridBox,
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  List<List<GestureDetector>> gridBoxes = snapshot.data;
                  int counter = 0;
                  int c = 0;
                  return Wrap(
                    children: gridBoxes.map((List<GestureDetector> list) {
                      ++c;
                      if (c == 18) c = 0;
                      print(c);
                      print('\n');
                      return list[c];
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => _changeColor(10, 10),
                    child: Text("change color"))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How many rows and how many columns each row must have?

Comment: Rows -34 and Columns - 18. I want to change the color of a container whenever the user taps on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that instead of `return list[c]` you must `return list`.

Here is a example with Strings that you can test in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/) and see the output. Hope it helps!

```
void main(){
  
  List<List<String>> _gridBox = List.generate(
      34, (index) => List<String>.generate(18, (index) => null));
  
  
  _generateBoxes() {
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
        _gridBox[i][j] = '[$i][$j]';
        //print('[$i][$j]');
      }
    return _gridBox;
  }
  
  
  List<List<String>> list2d = _generateBoxes();
  int c = 0;
  list2d.forEach((list) {
     print(c);           
     print(list);
     print('\n');
     ++c;
  });

}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to return anything from _generateboxes function, and I am facing problem while using streambuilder for showing the grid and change the color as soon as the user taps on a container as calling setState every time is not possible.

Comment: What i mean is that when you are mapping the lists, with this line `gridBoxes.map((List<GestureDetector> list)` , right bellow you wrote `return list[c]` and i'm saying that you should try to return just list, in this way: `return list`, to show all the 34 lines instead of 2.